# Country calling codes including area codes

Tags: sql, telephony

I'm trying to create a table full of calling country codes, so I can match phone numbers and retrieve their country of origin.

I'm aware of http://blog.attigohk.com/2010/12/12/countriesdb-free-country-code-sql-database/ and especially http://www.itu.int/ which contains the "official" list.

But I'm stuck on getting area codes as well, as Canada and USA share +1, so that's no good identifying a number only with +1.

Can anyone help me in the right direction, so "all the worlds" phone'numbers can be identified?

Comment: Welcome to the singular joys of the [North America Numbering Plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan)... Be careful in Northern Ireland - there are two different versions of each number depending on whether you're calling from the UK or RoI... Have fun with non-Metropolitan France... most importantly don't trust some random blog. One country has gone and 4 have been created since that post; that's assuming it was correct to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Wikipedia's lists [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_dialing_codes). For +1 you're going to have to use more digits to identify the country as it is also shared by various Caribbean nations. This other Wikipedia article breaks it down [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_North_American_Numbering_Plan_area_codes).

It may also be useful to have the list of international prefixes too (that is, the digits used to indicate you are dialing internationally). That list is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes). That can be handy in some environments where you can't be sure the format of the phone number provided to you. For example, some mobile carriers will send usage records with the number as dialled by the customer such as '+441234567890' as that is automatically converted to '0011441234567890' but some customers will dial that full number so you'll need to know which numbers to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

A database for **Area Codes** can be [downloaded from **here**](http://www.nanpa.com/area_codes/) (MS Access Format)

Answer (score 0):

The US and Canada share the +1 but the area codes differ and don't overlap. If you want to identify a phone number just select the country based on the country identifier and the first numbers of the area code. That way you'll get the correct country (and area code) even for the us and canada.